# Python : Bar out of the figure

Tags: python, matplotlib

I currently develop an application with matplotlib

Is it possible to ensure that if we have (for example) 30 bar charts, 20 are visible directly and the other 10 are hidden while waiting for the graph to scroll?

[Here a picture of what I would like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7kE6.png)

My code

```html
x = np.arange(len(list_machine))  # the label locations
    width = 0.20  # the width of the bars

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    rects1 = ax.bar(x - (width*3)/2, list_uturn_time_forward_X_300, width, label = "Axe : X / Velocity : 300")
    rects2 = ax.bar(x - width/2, list_uturn_time_forward_X_600, width, label = "Axe : X / Velocity : 600")
    rects2 = ax.bar(x + width/2, list_uturn_time_forward_Y_300, width, label = "Axe : Y / Velocity : 300")
    rects2 = ax.bar(x + (width*3)/2, list_uturn_time_forward_Y_600, width, label = "Axe : Y / Velocity : 600")

    # Add some text for labels, title and custom x-axis tick labels, etc.
    ax.set_ylabel('U turn value')
    ax.set_title('Uturn by Machine, Axis and Velocity')
    ax.set_xticks(x)
    ax.set_xticklabels(list_machine)
    ax.legend()

    fig.tight_layout()

    plt.show()
```

thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Have you tried `ax.set_xlim(..)`?

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.autoscale.html

Comment: Thank you so much @odjo, it's exactly what i want